# Double free or corruption (fasttop) while executing Parallel version

Tags: c++, dictionary, pthreads

I am trying to implement a serial algorithm in parallel manner using pthread.
Following is the code that i wrote -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
double similarity_score(char a,char b);
double find_array_max(double array[],int length);
void insert_at(char arr[], int n, int idx, char val);
void checkfile(int open, char filename[]);
void *main_algo(void* rank);
double valueChanger(int p1 , int p2);
string read_sequence(ifstream& f);

int ind;
double mu,delta;
double H_max = 0.;


int N_a;                     // get the actual lengths of the sequences
int N_b;

int** H;

int count_gap = 6;
int matrix_i = 1;
double temp[4];

char *nameof_seq_a;
char *nameof_seq_b;
string seq_a,seq_b;

 int bigCount;
 int start_i;
 int stop_i;
 int start_j;
 int stop_j;
 int stopSituation;
 int k;

    map<int,int> mymap;
    std::string strValue;
    std::stringstream out;
    std::stringstream out2;
    double value;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  // read info from arguments
  if(argc!=5){
    cout<<"Give me the propen number of input arguments:"<<endl<<"1 : mu"<<endl;
    cout<<"2 : delta"<<endl<<"3 : filename sequence A"<<endl<<"4 : filename sequence B"<<endl;
    cout<<"5 : maximal length N of sequences"<<endl;exit(1);
  }
  mu    = atof(argv[1]);
  delta = atof(argv[2]);
  /////////////////////////////////
  // give it the filenames
  nameof_seq_a = argv[3];
  nameof_seq_b = argv[4];
  //int N_max = atoi(argv[5]);


  // read the sequences into two vectors:
  ifstream stream_seq_b;                      // first define the input-streams for seq_a and seq_b
  stream_seq_b.open(nameof_seq_b);            // the same for seq_b
  checkfile(! stream_seq_b,nameof_seq_b);
  seq_b = read_sequence(stream_seq_b);
  ifstream stream_seq_a;
  stream_seq_a.open(nameof_seq_a);            // open the file for input
  checkfile(! stream_seq_a,nameof_seq_a);     // check, whether the file was opened successfully
  seq_a = read_sequence(stream_seq_a);


  // string s_a=seq_a,s_b=seq_b;
  N_a = seq_a.length();                     // get the actual lengths of the sequences
  N_b = seq_b.length();

  cout<<"N_a length "<<N_a<<endl;
  cout<<"N_b length "<<N_b<<endl;
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // initialize H
  int temp1 = N_a+1;
  int temp2 = N_b+1;

 // call to main algorithm
 bigCount = N_a;
 stopSituation = (N_a + N_b -1) /  count_gap;
 cout<<"--------Big Count----"<<bigCount<<endl;
 cout<<"--------stopSituation----"<<stopSituation<<endl;
 //cout<<"--------Matrix_i-------"<<matrix_i<<endl;
 while(matrix_i <= stopSituation+1){
    //cout<<"--------MATRIX_I----"<<matrix_i<<endl;
    pthread_t myThreads[matrix_i];
    for(k = 1; k < matrix_i +1 ; k++){
        if(k == 1){
            start_i = 1;
            stop_j = (count_gap * (matrix_i))+1;
        }
        else if(k == matrix_i){
            start_i = (count_gap * (k-1)) + 1;
            stop_j = count_gap +1;
        }
        else{
            start_i = (count_gap * (k-1)) + 1;
            stop_j = (count_gap * ((matrix_i - k)+1))+1;
        }

            start_j = (count_gap * (matrix_i - k))+1;
            stop_i = (count_gap * k)+1;

        //main_algo();
        pthread_create(&myThreads[k], NULL,main_algo, (void*)k);

        }
        //wait until all threads finish
        for(k = 1; k<matrix_i+1; k++){
            pthread_join(myThreads[k],NULL);
        }
   //sleep(1);
    if(matrix_i > 1)
    {

    }
    matrix_i++;
    }


  // Print the matrix H to the console
  cout<<"**************** Max is = "<<H_max<<endl;

mymap.clear();
} // END of main



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// auxiliary functions used by main:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


void checkfile(int open, char filename[]){

  if (open){cout << "Error: Can't open the file "<<filename<<endl;exit(1);}
  else cout<<"Opened file "<<filename<<endl;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
double valueChanger(int p1 , int p2){
    out.str(std::string());
    out2.str(std::string());
    out << p1;
    out2 << p2;
    strValue = out.str()+out2.str();
    double value_new = atoi(strValue.c_str());
    return value_new;
}

void *main_algo(void* rank){
//void main_algo(){


  // algorithm

  for(int i=start_i;i<stop_i;i++){
    if(i > N_a) {
    break;
    }
    for(int j=start_j;j<stop_j;j++){
    if(j > N_b){
    break;
    }
    int iCheck = i-1;
    int jCheck = j-1;

    value = valueChanger(iCheck , jCheck);
    //double myVal = H[iCheck][jCheck];
    double myVal;
    if ( mymap.find(value) == mymap.end() ) {
      // not found
    myVal = 0;
    } else {
      // found
    myVal = mymap.find(value)->second;
    }


    if(seq_a[i-1]==seq_b[j-1]){
    temp[0]=  myVal+1.0;
      }
    else{
         temp[0]= myVal-mu;
    }
    value = valueChanger(i-1 , j-1);
       if ( mymap.find(value) == mymap.end() ) {
      // not found
    temp[1] = 0;
    } else {
      // found
    temp[1] = mymap.find(value)->second-delta;
    }
    value = valueChanger(i , j-1);
     if ( mymap.find(value) == mymap.end() ) {
      // not found
    temp[2] = 0;
    } else {
      // found
    temp[2] = mymap.find(value)->second-delta;
    }

    temp[3] = 0.;
    value = valueChanger(i , j);
      mymap[value] = find_array_max(temp,4);

      if( H_max < mymap[value] ){
    H_max = mymap[value];
    }
     }
  }
cout<<"Done"<< my_rank<<endl;
}


double similarity_score(char a,char b){

  double result;
  if(a==b){
      result=1.;
    }
  else{
      result=-mu;
    }
  return result;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

double find_array_max(double array[],int length){

  double max = array[0];            // start with max = first element

  for(int i = 1; i<length; i++){
      if(array[i] > max){
    max = array[i];
      }
  }
  return max;                    // return highest value in array
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

string read_sequence(ifstream& f)
{
  // overflows.
  string seq;
  char line[5000];
  while( f.good() )
    {
      f.getline(line,5000);
      //        cout << "Line:" << line << endl;
      if( line[0] == 0 || line[0]=='#' )
    continue;
      for(int i = 0; line[i] != 0; ++i)
    {
      int c = toupper(line[i]);
     // cout << char(c);
      if( c != 'A' && c != 'G' && c != 'C' && c != 'T' )
        continue;

      seq.push_back(char(c));
    }
    }
  return seq;
}
```

Here , when i execute this program , i get following error

```
*** Error in `./myProg': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0xb5300480 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x767e2)[0xb74e67e2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77530)[0xb74e7530]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xb7689aaf]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSs4_Rep10_M_destroyERKSaIcE+0x1b)[0xb76ee5ab]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xad5f0)[0xb76ee5f0]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSs6assignERKSs+0x82)[0xb76efde2]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsaSERKSs+0x23)[0xb76efe33]
./myProg[0x80499dc]
./myProg[0x8049c2f]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6d78)[0xb7730d78]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xb75613de]
======= Memory map: ========
*** Error in `./myProg': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0829c8f8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x767e2)[0xb74e67e2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77530)[0xb74e7530]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xb7689aaf]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSs4_Rep10_M_destroyERKSaIcE+0x1b)[0xb76ee5ab]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xad5f0)[0xb76ee5f0]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsaSERKSs+0x23)[0xb76efe33]
./myProg[0x80499dc]
./myProg[0x8049aee]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6d78)[0xb7730d78]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please feel free to copy and execute with following two statements -
1) g++ [name].cpp -o [name] -lpthread
2) ./[name] 1 1 filetoread.txt filetoread2.txt

Please update for any kind of mistake i am doing in writing my code.
Thank you !!!!

Comment: I did not go through your code but I just want to point out that `std::map` is not thread-safe

Comment: Is there a way to make Map thread safe

Comment: @BeingCoder You need to use the normal pthread synchronisation primitives - you're modifying many global variables concurrently. Most of those globals seem inappropriate to share between threads. You should start with rewriting your single-threaded program without global variables. Then read about concurrent applications in a fine book.

Answer (score 0):

You need to protect any non-thread-safe variables (such as std::map) with a mutex (or other locking mechanism). Since you're using pthread, take a look at pthread_mutex_lock, pthread_mutex_unlock, and pthread_mutex_destroy.

Comment: I'd say that you need to protect any non-thread-safe *shared* variable with a mutex.

Comment: I tried locking and unlocking the Map updation within thread execution , but still error is same.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some notes if you want to go multithreading:

1. **don't** (unless you really need to) ... (multithreading brings a new world of complexity and problems)
2. .... If you really need to, **don't use more threads than processors** (this is becoming muddled in recent years with CPUs/cores/hyperthreads... but what I mean by processor is what the hardware or virtualization allows you to run in parallel) (otherwise you will have scheduling contention at the OS/hardware level)
3. lock (mutexes) **all** common data access.... (otherwise you will corrupt your common data)
4. .... but try to **lock the least possible time**. (because every time you lock it means that all your threads need to wait and they will be doing nothing).
5. and don't use locks unless you need to (because locking/unlocking is *expensive*)
6. Avoid locking by **using processing queues** (e.g. to deliver commands or deliver results across threads). Instead of locking while processing the command/result, you can lock only while inserting/removing from the queue.
7. Avoid locking by subdividing map-like single structure (with a single mutex) into an **array of map-like structure (with an array of mutexes)** indexed with a hash of the key of the original map. Instead of locking all threads, you will be locking only some of them.
8. If there's an unbalance between readers/writers, **try a read/write mutex** to minimize contention. Ths will allow multiple simultaneous readers or one writer.